# Obj C - How do I apply a GPUImage filter on top of a video that is playing on a loop in a AVPlayer (video player)?

Tags: ios, objective-c, avfoundation, gpuimage

I have a video I am playing using AVPlayer, but I want to apply a swipeable filter view like snapchat to the video while its playing on AVPlayer. So I was wondering how I can use GPUImage filters (such as black and white) to apply filters on the AVPlayer.

NOTE: I know how to write the filter onto a movie file, but I will only do that when the user saves the video, but I want them to be able to swipe through filters and see how it looks like.

Comment: Hi, Did you solve this? I'm searching but couldn't figure out how to add GPUImage filter (Specially Lookup Filter ) to AVPlayer.